# Request to reopen question 216839

Tags: support, reopen-request

I believe this question was closed by mistake. There is enough information to answer the question. I also edited to clean it up a little. Honestly, it really didn't need it. Now it looks slightly more professional.

https://superuser.com/q/216839/20433

Comment: FYI, the user can still accept your answer, although for an unregistered user after several month the chance is low. It just means there can be no additional answers by others.

Comment: There's only one other answer there by a user named "boston" which appears to be a duplicate of your helpful answer, except that it replaces steps 3 through 8 with "**Write x-mas card for relatives**."  I have flagged that other answer for deletion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The question is *really* old, has been abandoned by the OP, it's got low views, has got <s>two</s> one good answer and not to mention there's not much infomation on the question.

I don't see why it needs to be reopened. If the community wishes to reopen it, they can cast their re-open votes and we'll judge the feedback. As of now, it remains closed.

Comment: I'm also convinced it should remain closed.

Comment: The user actually asked and never returned after it was posted, the time of last seen and the question being posted are the same. I also think it's clear that they don't intend to return for an answer.

Comment: @Simon Sheehan:  ...or their computer crashed and they can't remember the web site address.  =(